# error 1004 unable to get the unique property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, unique, autofilter

I have written a script to insert a range of cells into a list box of the userform in 3 steps:

1. The main table (A2:N...) gets filtered to a specific value in column A.
2. The values in column G get put into a range, then a sorted array with unique values.
3. The array is inputed in the listbox

I am getting the error 1004 regarding the "unique" function on rang1. I don't understand what is the issue.

Can someone kindly help me?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rang, rang1,  As Range
Dim lstrow, x As Long
Dim ListUniq(), ListNoEmpty(), As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set rang = ws.Range("B3").CurrentRegion
lstrow = rang.Rows.Count + 1

'Step1.The main table (A2:N...) get's filtered to a specific (Dental) value on column A.
ws.Range("$A$2:$N$" & lstrow).AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:="Dental", _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


'Step2.The values in column G get put into a range, then a sorted array with unique values.
Set rang1 = Range("G2:G" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

ReDim ListUniq(WorksheetFunction.CountA(rang2))
ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.Unique(rang1)
ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.sort(ListUniq)

'Resize Array prior to loading data
ReDim ListNoEmpty(WorksheetFunction.CountA(ListUniq))
'Step3.The array is inputed in the listbox
'Loop through each cell in Range and store value in Array
x = 0

For Each cell In ListUniq
    If cell <> "" Then
        ListNoEmpty(x) = cell
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next cell

ProviderListBx.list = ListNoEmpty

End Sub
```

Comment: 1 : Is there a reason you `redim ListUniq` but using `rang2` instead of `rang1` ? 2 : Is your version of Excel supports Unique formula ? Excel doesnt feature Unique and Sort formulas before version 1911

Answer (score 1):

### Unique Values to Listbox

- This will work for any version of Excel i.e. it doesn't use the `Unique` and `Sort` functions but it uses a dictionary and an ascending integer sequence in a helper column instead.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    PopulateProviderListBox
End Sub

Sub PopulateProviderListBox()
    Const ProcName As String = "PopulateProviderListBox"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    ' Turn off AutoFilter.
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False 
    
    ' Reference the range ('rg').
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("A2")
    Dim rg As Range
    With fCell.CurrentRegion
        Set rg = fCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - fCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - fCell.Column)
    End With
    
    ' Expand the range by one column and reference it ('nrg').
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count + 1
    Dim nrg As Range: Set nrg = rg.Resize(, cCount)
    
    ' Write an ascending integer sequence to the (new) helper column.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    nrg.Columns(cCount).Value = ws.Evaluate("=ROW(1:" & rCount & ")")
    
    ' Sort the new range by the lookup column ('7').
    nrg.Sort nrg.Columns(7), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    ' Reference the data (no headers) of the lookup column ('lrg').
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = nrg.Columns(7).Resize(rCount - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Filter the new range by the criteria in the criteria column ('1').
    nrg.AutoFilter 1, "Dental"
        
    ' Attempt to reference all visible cells ('vrg') of the lookup column.
    Dim vrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = lrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Turn off the autofilter.
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If Not vrg Is Nothing Then
        ' Return the unique (sorted) values
        ' in the keys of a dictionary ('dict').
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim vCell As Range
        For Each vCell In vrg.Cells
            dict(vCell.Value) = Empty
        Next vCell
        ' Return the unique (sorted) values in the listbox.
        If dict.Count > 0 Then ProviderListBx.List = dict.Keys
    End If
    
    ' Sort the new range by the helper column to regain initial order.
    nrg.Sort nrg.Columns(cCount), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    ' Clear the helper column.
    nrg.Columns(cCount).Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Vbasic2008.  I am not totally understanding your approach and wouldn't know how to adjust it properly to fit in my macro (that has more code then what I showed). But I will circle back to it if anything else fails. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you Excel version accepts `UNIQUE` and `Sort` formulas and then `WorksheetFunction` methods, both of them do not behave **exactly** as Excel respective formulas...

`WorksheetFunction.UNIQUE` does not work on discontinuous ranges.
The next line, returns such a range:

```
  Set rang1 = Range("G2:G" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Even `ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.sort(rang1)` does not work because of the above mentioned behavior. If `ListUniq` would be a continuous range it will work.

Then, declaring `Dim ListUniq()` makes useless the line `ReDim ListUniq(WorksheetFunction.CountA(rang2))`, which anyhow uses an non existing range. Probably, it is a type and it should be `rang1`, but still useless. VBA is able to return the array **without needing a previous `ReDim`**. Only the range to be continuous.

In such cases, a function transforming the discontinuous range in a continuous array would solve your issue:

```
Private Function ListUniqFromDiscR_2D(rng As Range) As Variant 'makes 2D (one column) array from a discontinuous range
    Dim A As Range, ListUniq, count As Long, i As Long
    
    ReDim ListUniq(1 To rng.cells.count, 1 To 1): count = 1
    For Each A In rng.Areas
            For i = 1 To A.cells.count
                ListUniq(count, 1) = A.cells(i).Value: count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    ListUniqFromDiscR_2D = ListUniq
End Function
```

It can be used in your code as:

```
   Set rang1 = Range("G2:G" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   ListUniq = ListUniqFromDiscR_2D(rang1)            'the continuous extracted array
    Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(ListUniq), "|") 'just to visually see the (continuous) returned array
    ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.unique(ListUniq)  'the unique elements array
    ListUniq = WorksheetFunction.Sort(ListUniq)    'the unique sorted array
     Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(ListUniq), "|") 'just to the unique, sorted array (in Immediate Window)...
```

But if your Excel version is not able to handle `Unique` and `Sort`, there are not standard VBA functions doing it very fast. If this is your case, I can also post such functions.

Comment: Hello FaneDuru, thank you so much for your help. the function "ListUniqFromDiscR_2D" did not work for me. would you have any idea why or any alternative solution?

Comment: I got the error message "Byref argument type mistmatch" related to my rang1. Would you know why?

Comment: Did you use the code lines  **exactly as they are above**? I mean, used the range, not its value...

Comment: Yes I pasted the private sub exactly the way you wrote it. The only thing I changed was the rng by rang1 in the line "ListUniq = ListUniqFromDiscR_2D(rng)"

Comment: I looked to see what was the type of rang1 with  vartype(rang1). It returned 8204 which is apparently the computation of vbArray + vbVariant. That's why I'm getting the mistmatch. I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Ngabo Forget about 'varType`... Try `TypeName(rang1)`, but if you did not change anything, it should return "Range". Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If available, I would like to connect and see what's happening in your workbook.

Comment: I tried TypeName(rang1) and it came back as a range, I am still getting the mistmatch error message. I wouldn'T be able to share more for privacy reasons.

Comment: @Ngabo Then, I cannot understand what's happening in your case. It is not the first time I use the above function... Are you sure that the respective range is set? I mean, does the filter return a range of visible cells in that specific case? You speak about `Range("G2:G" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` I suppose... Am I right?

Comment: yes it does. I have 17 rows of data after the filter. I just want to remind you that I have made one modification from the code you suggested. I changed "ListUniq = ListUniqFromDiscR_2D(rng)" to "ListUniq = ListUniqFromDiscR_2D(rang1)".

Comment: @Ngabo You were correct. I posted the code I tested on my computer... I already edited my answer and correct it as you say. Without seeing it I do not know what's happening... Try `Debug.print rng1.address`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`?